# PHP code working on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, mysqli

Here's the following code for simple fetch operation:-

```
        $con = new mysqli('localhost','xyz','xyz','xyz');

        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT u.name,u.email,u.api_key,u.status FROM users u WHERE u.email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$email);
        if($stmt->execute()){

            $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
            var_dump($user);
            $stmt->close();

        }else{
            echo 'null';
        }
```

It does not prints 'null', but prints nothing. 
Is it the difference between PHP version which is 5.5 at localhost and 5.4.9 at server ?

Comment: And you have your database in your server just like your local machine? Have you checked server logs (in linux: /var/log/apache2/ folder)

Comment: Check the error output of your statement, if the execution fails.

Comment: The mysqli driver is enabled on server? Enable error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @Hardy - Yup the database is exported from local and imported to server.

Comment: @Maykonn - okay i'll check that.

Comment: @Maykonn - no luck. if i print $stmt->num_rows. It prints 1 but unable to fetch associative array.

Comment: So have you verified that you have data in that database..? With passed email..? And email is not empty..?

Comment: Yup i tested the same thing with procedural mysqli. It is working fine. As i said when i print $stmt->num_rows it returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to see what happens :

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','xyz','xyz','xyz');
if(!$con){
    die("Error : " . mysqli_error);
}
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT u.name,u.email,u.api_key,u.status FROM users u WHERE u.email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$email);
if($stmt->execute()){
    $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    var_dump($user);
    $stmt->close();
}else{
    echo 'null';
}
```

Comment: Tried but no luck. I am able to connect to database.

Comment: Yes. The problem is at get_result() i guess which returns nothing.

Comment: Ever, verify the result before execute a fetch. This will avoid many problems.

Comment: `if($stmt === ""){die("Data is blank.");}`

Comment: Again?? You should really consider reading documentations about get_result() and fetch_assoc() and something like this. Also learn about some more SQL.

Comment: Hey, did I see `FROM users u`? Do you think a mistake is there?